# How does the Chrome browser handle the scroll position of a container with changing content? How to avoid that?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, frontend

Chrome browser automatically adjusts the scrollTop of the container when the content of the container is changing. In the following test case, if I scrolled the "target" element in the middle of the viewport, I observed that in Chrome the console.log outputs a different value every time. But in the Safari and Firefox, the console.log outputs always the same value.

My question is that how we can avoid Chrome doing this smart scrolling action for the changing content of a container?

Here is the example in Angular:

HTML:

```
<h3>{{ message }}</h3>
<div class="container"
  #container>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of arrayData">
    <div class="item"
      [style.background]=" item === target ? '#f00' : '#fff'">
      {{ item.text }}
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.container {
  height: 800px;
  overflow: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;

  background: #ccc;

  .item {
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
  }
}
```

Javascript:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  public message: string;

  arrayData: any[];
  target: any;

  @ViewChild('container')
  container: ElementRef;

  constructor() {
    this.arrayData = [];
    this.target = {
      text: ' Target String. '
    };
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.message = 'Hello';

    setInterval(() => {
      if (this.container !== undefined) {
        console.log(this.container.nativeElement.scrollTop);
      }

      const n = Math.random() * 10 + 2;
      const m = Math.random() * 10 + 2;

      this.arrayData = [this.target];

      for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        this.arrayData.unshift({
          text: 'Up ' + i
        });
      }

      for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        this.arrayData.push({
          text: 'Down ' + i
        });
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and fixed it thanks to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64566362/10997015). The problem seems to be [the scroll anchoring feature](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/scroll-anchoring/) implemented by Chrome. There is good information about it in [the GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-scroll/issues/138).

To fix the issue, set the CSS property

```css
overflow-anchor: none;
```

to the scroll host element.

More information about `overflow-anchor` [can be found in the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-anchor).